# Python unittest expected failures ignored in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-unittest

I would like to upgrade my python test harness - which is based on Python's unittest module - from Python2 to Python3. However, the `unittest.expectedFailure` decorator doesn't seem to have the same effect anymore. In particular, the following code has different behavior depending on the Python version even though the specifications are virtually identical:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python2
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# Switch between the two lines above to get the different outcome

import unittest

class ComparisonTests(unittest.TestCase):

    def runTest(self):
        """ This method is needed even if empty """

    def add_test(self, the_suite):
        def testMain():
            self.testFunc()
        testMain = unittest.expectedFailure(testMain)
        the_case = unittest.FunctionTestCase(testMain)
        the_suite.addTest(the_case)

    def testFunc(self):
        self.assertTrue(False)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    SUITE = unittest.TestSuite()
    ComparisonTests().add_test(SUITE)

    the_runner = unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2)
    the_runner.run(SUITE)
```

If I keep the first line (`#!/usr/bin/env python2`) and run on MacOS `10.14.1` and Python `2.7.15` then the output is the following:

```
unittest.case.FunctionTestCase (testMain) ... expected failure

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK (expected failures=1)
```

This is the behavior I expect. However, if I switch to the second line (`#!/usr/bin/env python3`) which will use Python `3.7.3` I get the following:

```
unittest.case.FunctionTestCase (testMain) ... FAIL

======================================================================
FAIL: unittest.case.FunctionTestCase (testMain)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./unittest_test_2.py", line 12, in testMain
    self.testFunc()
  File "./unittest_test_2.py", line 18, in testFunc
    self.assertTrue(False)
AssertionError: False is not true

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

It looks like the `unittest.expectedFailure` decorator was ignored. Looking at the source code I can see a clear difference:

```py
# Python 3.7 source:
def expectedFailure(test_item):
    test_item.__unittest_expecting_failure__ = True
    return test_item

# Python 2.7 source:
def expectedFailure(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            func(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception:
            raise _ExpectedFailure(sys.exc_info())
        raise _UnexpectedSuccess
    return wrapper
```

How can I define expected failures in the Python3 version of unittest ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python 3 version of the `unittest.expectedFailure` decorator is expected to operate on a unittest test case and not on a method as it did in Python 2. So in order for the above test harness to work with Python 3 one needs to use the `expectedFalure` decorator on `the_case` as follows:

```py
the_case = unittest.FunctionTestCase(testMain)
the_case = unittest.expectedFailure(the_case)
```